# Data into classes, timing, procedure

Tags: oop, class, orm

I have a style/good code question. It's one of those "not that important because it's working" things but still, I'd like some insight from the community. I'm in C# but the methodology could apply to anything OOP

So I have a class, it's essentially a container for data. I pass the class to the database instead of passing 10 parameters. The database writing class drops each data member into it's respective SQL parameter and executes the stored procedure in my database.

My question is, when I am collecting data into the class I have all of them attached to Change events. Like

```
private void chkIce_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;

        if (chk.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            outTruck.setWeather(2, true);
        else
            outTruck.setWeather(2, false);

    }
```

and

```
    private void txtTrailer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        newRecord.TrailerNumber = txt.Text.ToString();
    }
```

This goes in and sets the ice value of my class to true/false based on what the user selects. Or sets the text. It's pretty straightforward, but there is a bit of code overhead as in each control has it's own event (also the cast on sender line might be overkill). The other way would be to collect all the data at submit. Drop it all into the class then. There was something else called entity framework and ORM, but I am at the moment stuck in .NET 3.5(we are with the times) and I've read that does not apply until you get to 4.0. I've not really read if there is a standard, it seems to be more preference than anything. So, fellow stack overlowieans...what are your thoughts?

Comment: Have a discussion! I need to get my form data into my class. I have option 1. All the control's onChange puts it there or 2. Collect the data with the submit button.

Comment: 2nd option is right bcoz it works faster

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're in a web page with post back, I think it's easier to have that submit button handler functions where you instantiate your object, and manually set each property to the value of its corresponding UI element. Doing the data setting on every event handler (selection changed, focus out, etc.) would require the entire page to reload. (Then, you would have to persist that object across those post backs - a tedious and error prone feat, though doable.)

Even in a desktop project, I would collect all of the values from all UI elements to build my object, in that submit button's event handler.

You would want to implement event handlers on certain UI elements if the change of state in that UI element will affect something other than the object itself. For example, a checkbox may determine whether or not the user will be able to submit - because checking it so might add a feature that costs more where the total price of their order might exceed their current balance. This is when you would check to see whether the submit button should remain enabled or become disabled.